# Asynchronous XMLHttpRequest send() returns before all data is sent?

Tags: javascript, ajax, concurrency, send

When you do something like

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

the send() function fires a thread (or something like that) to send the HTTP message concurrently, or it sends and then only after all data is sent it returns?

Comment: First, Ajax is a technique, and XHR objects are like API conforming type instances... when you 'send' requests to resources (uri, endpoints). a connection (stream) between the client and server is established and it remains open until it's closed.. if you're asking whether the established connection remains open until all data is sent, the answer is the connection can be severed by a number of things; the stream can be closed by the user-agent/client while the response is being buffered... it's tentative.. but the server will close the stream when it's written all the data. I'll find the spec.

Comment: Ok. Being more specific. I have a bunch of bytes to send through the socket connection, right? Is there any risk of losing these bytes if, after send() returns, I do something like formfield.value = ""; ?

Comment: you mean if you were to modify the form field variables in the next statement after sending the request?

Comment: javascript is single threaded, and it shares the same thread as the UI. when you call send, you will not be able to modify anything or execute any lines until it returns to the function scope. that means the data, both declared on the XHR object and processed by the xhr.send method/stack cannot be modified before it is sent. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks! That's just what I wanted to read.

Answer (score 0):

xmlhttp.send() never return, it is **void**, it only make the request to the server, the xmlhttp object that you created has a method called **onreadystatechange**, which is called when your asynchronous request success or fail, anyways your application flow it is not corrupted, it keep going. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Haha, so void functions do not return? They do not terminate? Hahaha.

This answer is not helpful. I asked if the send() function terminates before all the TCP socket stuff is done.